# Does this category-like structure have a name?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I have the following structure that to me looks like some kind of "bipartite category":

- There are two sorts of objects $A$ and $B$
- Arrows only go from objects of $A$ to objects of $B$, so they all have form $f : a \to b$ where $a : A$ and $b : B$
- Composition is only allowed via compatibility relation $R \subseteq B \times A$: if you have $f : a \to b$ and $g : a' \to b'$, then $g \circ f : a \to b'$ exists iff $bRa'$
- Composition (where allowed) is associative as usual.

(I am being vague if $A$ and $B$ are sets or not, but if that matters, I am happy to restrict them to be sets.)

Is there an established structure like this? If not, is there at least something of which the above is a special case of?

## Motivation / Context

I received two comments asking for more context, so here's a brief description of where I'm coming from.

First, suppose you want to describe a process made up of discrete steps. You could model it with a category where the objects are states, and the steps you can take are arrows: the domain is the start state, and the codomain is the end state. This works out nicely because identity morphisms correspond to not taking any steps at all, and composition is just sequencing.

Now, I am in a situation where instead of characterizing steps by their start and end state, I'd like to characterize them as an input interface and an output interface. The only extra structure I want to impose is that there is a way to tell (proof-irrelevantly) if an output interface can be connected to the next input interface. So the $A$ and the $B$ in my question would stand for the possible input and output interfaces, and $R$ is the compatibility relation.

Comment: Just to clarify, are there identity arrows? I'm guessing not from the second condition

Comment: Identity arrows wouldn't make sense because the domain and codomain of arrows are different.

Comment: @RobPratt: thanks for the tag edit, for some reason I was searching for "nomenclature" instead of "terminology"...

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did this arise?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: see [this /r/haskell thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/it5yar/a_very_typed_container_for_representing_microcode/): the problem description is in my linked blog post, and the structure above is what we came up with in the commen thread.

Comment: If you ignore the absence of identity arrows, then this is a special case of a category: there is at most one arrow (given by $R$) from an object of $B$ to an object of $A$, and no arrows between objects of $A$ or of $B$.

Comment: I don't understand how any compositions exist. For $f : a \to b$ and $g : a' \to b'$ to have a composition (in the usual categorical sense) we need $b = a'$ but you just said that $b$ and $a'$ are objects of two different types. Is there a typecasting operator around you haven't made explicit? Also, I think it is a very bad idea to write down a formalism like this which excludes identity morphisms. Can you explain what the motivation is in more detail (but hopefully not requiring too much Haskell background)? I can't make heads or tails of the reddit thread.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have extended my question with my motivation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: well I am *not* claiming this is a category. The definition of composition should be taken as fiat, and I am looking for structures (which actually might have nothing to do with categories) that are similar. I only brought up categories because that's the closest thing I can think of.

Comment: @Cactus: can you say more about what it means to connect an input and output interface? Describing this in terms of a relation seems to imply that if such a connection exists then it's unique. Is that true in your setting? If not, does composition depend on how the interfaces are connected? (What I'm trying to get at is that it really sounds to me like you secretly want morphisms from $B$ to $A$. Actually I guess your structure can be modeled by a non-unital category, where $A$ is the collection of all sources and $B$ is the collection of all targets, and the relation $R$ is equality.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, that's what I meant by compatibility being proof-irrelevant: if a given $b : B$ is compatible with a given $a' : A$, then that's all you need to know. There is no "content" to this compatibility. So if they were morphisms back from $B$ to $A$, you could have at most one for each pair of $b$ and $a'$.

Answer (score 2):

As Kevin Arlin comments, this setup can be realized by considering

1. a category $\mathcal H$, with two disjoint full subcategories $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$, such that their union contains all objects of $\mathcal H$.
2. Both $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are discrete.
   **Edit:** As written in the comments, in order to make this indeed a category, we have to add the compositions of internal morphisms like $a\to b\to a'$, so that they are **not discrete** in any interesting scenario: either we are really assuming some morphisms in $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$, or we can freely add the missing compositions.
3. Moreover, $|\hom(b,a)|\le 1$ for each $a\in\mathcal A,\,b\in\mathcal B$.
   **Edit:** According to above edit, neither this makes sense in the general case if $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$ are not discrete. The closest thing we can assume is that if there's an arrow ending at object $a\in\mathcal A$, then $a$ has a *coreflection* in $\mathcal B$.

Note that 1. can be rephrased as a category $\mathcal H$ over 'the generic isomorphic pair of objects', that is, a functor $\mathcal H\to \mathcal I$ where $\mathcal I$ is the category with 2 objects $x,y$ and 2 nonidentity arrows $x\to y$ and $y\to x$:
Simply send objects of $\mathcal A$ to $x$ and objects of $\mathcal B$ to $y$.

By the way, it's essentially the same as a *Morita context* in the bicategory of profunctors.

Comment: While this is what I said, I think it's not precisely right, since if you go from $a\to b$ and then $b\to a'$, you'll get an induced morphism $a\to a'$. Instead of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ being discrete, it seems we need to say that morphisms of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are freely generated from the given morphisms from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$ and back.

Comment: Hmm.. That makes sense.

Comment: I'll hold on waiting for another answer, because it is a bit like saying the answer is "set, with some extra constraints". The ideal answer would be some named concept that can be used in a descirption/documentation both to import intuition and also to say "you can use this for this purpose as-is, or you can read up on the wider theory by starting from this name".

Comment: I understand. Kevin's original comment would have been a clearer answer, but with these edits I also feel it less satisfactory.